# Rails: Check if association exists on Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, activesupport-concern

In a concern I run this code:

```
self.user&.favorite(self, scope: [:watching]) if self.respond_to? user
self.team&.user.favorite(self, scope: [:watching]) if self.respond_to? team
```

I included this concern in `User` & `Team`.
Everytime I create a `User`, I get the following error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<User:0xb0e9020>

Same goes for creating a `Team`.

Why does this happen? Obviously `User` has no method (or equivalent) that responds to user on an instance. But thats why I added `if self.respond_to? user` to the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [respond_to?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) receives symbol as an argument

```
self.user&.favorite(self, scope: [:watching]) if self.respond_to? :user
self.team&.user.favorite(self, scope: [:watching]) if self.respond_to? :team
```

That's why if a `user` or `team` method is not defined, you'll receive the error.